# Queen moves function does not return correct number of moves

Tags: python, function, chess, python-chess

This is my function to calculate all the possible moves for the queen's Diagonals:

```
def dia(n, r_q, c_q, obs):
    ans = 0

    # up right
    cnt = 1
    while cnt + r_q <= n and cnt + c_q <= n:
        if [cnt + r_q, cnt + c_q] in obs:
            break
        ans += 1 
        cnt += 1
    
    # down left    
    cnt = 1
    while r_q - cnt >= 1 and c_q - cnt >= 1: 
        if [r_q - cnt, c_q - cnt] in obs:
            break
        ans += 1 
        cnt += 1

    # left up
    cnt = 1
    while r_q - cnt >= 1 and c_q + cnt <= n:      
        if [r_q - cnt, c_q + cnt] in obs:
            break
        print([r_q - cnt, c_q + cnt])
        ans += 1 
        cnt += 1

    # right down   
    cnt = 1
    while r_q + cnt <= n and c_q - cnt >= 1:      
        if [r_q + cnt, c_q - cnt]  in obs:
            break
        print([r_q + cnt, c_q - cnt])
        ans += 1 
        cnt += 1
    return ans
```

The parameters are:

- `n` The board size, i.e. `n=8` means it is an 8x8 board.
- `r_q` Queen's row,
- `c_q` Queen's column,
- `obs` All obstacles that reside on the diagonals of the queen.

Sometimes it does not provide the right number of possible moves.

What am I missing, and how can I fix or find a better implementation of this function?

[image: chess board]

Comment: If the obstacle piece is of the opposite color (and not the king,, but that should never happen)you need to add one before break because capturing that piece is a legal move.

Comment: no, I do not want to consider capturing the pieces, for example as you can see at the picture the possible moves are only 10 excluding the obstacles( in other words consider them like if the obstacles are the pieces from the same team).

Comment: The image shows that vertical and horizontal lines should also be scanned. Your code only looks at the diagonals. Your question's text says you want to count the possibilities on the diagonals: if that is purpose, your code returns the correct result: 6. But the image includes also the moves on the straight lines, which then amounts to 10. Just add that logic too if that is what you need.

Comment: I know that, I have already build functions that will calculate the possible moves in the row and the column ,still the diagonal, and the moves in the row and the columns are calculated just fine the only problem is this function.

Comment: Please give a *re-creatable example* where your code does not output correctly.

Comment: obs = [[2, 3], [7, 8], [9, 10], [1, 2]], n = 10, r_q = 5, c_q = 6, the output when these parameters are given the output should be 11 but it returns 12

Comment: For that example your function returns 12 (for the diagonals). That is correct. Why do you think it should be 11? Which is the square that you feel should not be counted?

Comment: I also get 12 in that example. (1,10), (2, 9), (3, 4), (3,8), (4,5), (4,7), (6, 5), (6, 7), (7, 4), (8, 3), (9, 2), (10, 1)

Comment: sorry for bothering I found what I was doing wrong this functions works just fine, thank you guys for the help

Answer (score 0):

This code is better and you can just use this to get both(diagonals and straights).

```
queenpos = [x, x]
directions = [(1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, -1)]
for dir in directions:
    for m in [-1, 1]:
        d = dir * m
        for i in range(8):
            row = queenpos[0] + d[0]
            col = queenpos[1] + d[1]
            if row < 8 and row > -1 and col < 8 and col > -1:
            obs = board.getpiece(row, col)
            if obs is not None: break
            print(row, col)
```

It is a bit hard to understand but it should work.